# IP address set to static, cannot get connection to server

Tags: azure, networking, network-protocols, static-ip-address

I set my server with static IP address from the Network and Sharing Center. My server is an Azure VM. After setting it with static IP, i lost connection to my Machine. I check from the portal.azure.com, the server status is running but i realize that the network out dropped to 0MB.

I can't remote desktop to the server, I tried restart the server from Azure, but it doesn't come back alive (At this point i mean i can't remote desktop to it).

What can i do next? Is that's all? I just screw up my server?

Please help! I believe there's some miracle to let it get back to life.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/) describes the correct way to set internal private static IP addresses to azure VMs (using Powershell).  You can try the step "How to remove a static internal IP from a VM" but I'm not sure if it will undo the change you've made within the OS - did you try shutting down the VM completely and restarting it?

ps- this question probably suits Server Fault rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. Didn't notice this question until now.

Actually, the server is no longer accessible after setting the IP address. Later then I found out you shouldn't set a static IP for an Azure VM. It should be assigned by DHCP.

So.. lesson learn i guess.. :I